# Javascript : time addition

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a **begin date** like this :

```
var beginDate = "29/04/2015";
var beginHour = "13:32";
```

I have some duration variables :

```
var hourDuration = "2";
var minuteDuration = "10";
```

I have to calculate the **end date** :

I my example, i attempt to get :

```
var endDate = "29/04/2015";
var endHour = "15:42";
```

But if the user set a long hour time for the duration, the endDate must take into account that the end will be another day.

Is there a way in JavaScript to calculate this times ?

Comment: JavaScript has a `Date` type. Don't do it on yourself.

Answer (score 2):

without any libraries this would look like this:

```js
var beginDate = "29/04/2015";
var beginHour = "13:32";

var hourDuration = "2";
var minuteDuration = "10";

var date = beginDate.split('/'), time = beginHour.split(':');
date = new Date(date[2], date[1] - 1, date[0], time[0], time[1]);
var newDate = new Date(+date + (hourDuration * 60 + +minuteDuration) * 60000);

var endDate = newDate.getDate() + '/' + (newDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + newDate.getFullYear();
var endHour = newDate.getHours() + ':' + newDate.getMinutes();

alert( endDate + ' ' + endHour);
```

But I would recommend to use `momentjs`

Comment: Thank you a lot. You solved my painful "playing" with time!

Answer (score 1):

To have it really accurate you can use the "Date" object in Javascript. Be careful it is aware of the local timezone. The script underneath shows 17:42 instead of 15:42 if you are in GMT+2 (like me :)).

```js
var beginDate = "29/04/2015";
var beginHour = "13:32";

var dateo = new Date(beginDate.split("/").reverse().join("-")  + "T" + beginHour + ":00");

var hourDuration = "2";
var minuteDuration = "10";

var enddate = new Date(dateo.getTime() + (hourDuration * 3600000) + (minuteDuration * 60000 ));

alert(enddate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a built in Date object, that can parse RFC2822 compatible date-strings. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

However, your string does not conform to the RFC2822-specification(without prior alterations).

I would therefore recommend you to use momentjs. It's a very convenient library for date/time operations. For instance, to add two hours from your given date, you could type.

```
var timeString = '29/04/2015 13:32';
var time = moment(timeString, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:ss').add(2, 'hour');
console.log(time.format('mm/dd/yyyy hh:ss') );
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in Date type from JavaScript:

```
var date= new Date(2015, 04, 29, 13, 32, 0);
date.setHours(beginDate.getHours()+2);
date.setMinutes(beginDate.getMinutes()+10);

alert( date.getDate() + '/' + date.getMonth() + 1 + '/' +  date.getFullYear() +
       " " + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() );
```